# How to change the information when clicking on a marker in React-leaflet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

I have a React-leaflet map on the left side with markers placed on it. On the right side there is a list of point names. I need that when clicking on a certain marker, the name of the point that corresponds to the marker becomes 1st in the list. I take the coordinates of the points and the name of the places from the Firestore. How can I implement this behavior?
App.js:

```js
function App() {
  const [selectedHouse, setSelectedHouse] = useState();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <div className="map-content">
        <Map onSelect={setSelectedHouse} />
        <List selectedHouse={selectedHouse} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Map.js:

```js
const Map = ({ onSelect }) => {
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "map-markers"));
    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      setCoordinates(
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        }))
      );
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <MapContainer
        center={center}
        zoom={13}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
        style={{ height: "100vh" }}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        {coordinates.map((coord, index) => (
          <Marker
            key={index}
            eventHandlers={{
              click: () => {
                onSelect(index);
              },
            }}
            position={[parseFloat(coord.data.lat), parseFloat(coord.data.lon)]}
            icon={defaultIcon}
          />
        ))}
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

List.js:

```js
const List = ({ selectedHouse }) => {
  const [houseTitles, setHouseTitle] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "map-markers"));
    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      setHouseTitle(
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        }))
      );
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "50%" }}>
      {houseTitles
        .filter((title, index) => index !== selectedHouse)
        .map((title, index) => (
          <ListItem key={index} title={title.data.title} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image]

Comment: In `Map.js` are you certain `eventHandlers={{click: () => {(onSelect(index))}}}` is working correctly?

Comment: Yes, eventHandlers is used for the marker, it does not have onClick

Comment: Now I have 4 houses and 4 markers. When I click on a marker (on any marker), one name is removed, there are 3 of them and they somehow switch randomly

Answer (score 0):

In your `List.js` you need to add the selected house before the `.map` part so that the selected house properly appears:

```
    <div style={{ width: "50%" }}>
      {<ListItem title={houseTitles[selectedHouse]} />}
      {houseTitles
        .filter((title, index) => index !== selectedHouse)
        .map((title, index) => (
          <ListItem key={index} title={title.data.title} />
        ))}
    </div>
```