# How to display the desired information on click ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My page is divided into right and left parts. On the left side there are 3 buttons, and on the right side there is a list with 3 texts. They are in different files. I want the corresponding text to come first in the list when the button is clicked. The functionality is similar to tabs, but I don’t know how to implement it, because the components are in different files and are not connected. How can I do that?

```js
//Buttons.js

const btnArr = [
["Togle Text 1"],
["Togle Text 2"],
["Togle Text 3"],
];

const Buttons = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "50%" }}>
        {btn.map((btn, index) => (
          <Button
            key={index}
            text={btn}
          />
      ))}
  );
};

//Text.js

const btnArr = [
["Text 1"],
["Text 2"],
["Text 3"],
];

const Texts = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "50%" }}>
        {texts.map((txt, index) => (
          <Text
            key={index}
            text={txt}
          />
      ))}
  );
};
```

Comment: Take the static arrays to one parent component. There you can add logic to sort them based on button that is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Parent Component

You'll want to use a `useState` in a parent component of both `Texts` and `Buttons`. That way you can keep track of which button has been clicked, and you'll pass `Buttons` a way to update which has been clicked. You'll also be able to pass `Texts` the value of which text is currently selected.

That parent component could look like this:

```
  const [selectedText, setSelectedText] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div
    >
      <Buttons onSelect={setSelectedText} />
      <Texts selectedText={selectedText} />
    </div>
  );
```

#### Buttons Component

Next we'll handle the `Buttons` Component. You can see in the above codeblock we are passing `Buttons` a prop called `onSelect` which we'll use to update the `selectedText` state.

Here's what that component could look like:

```
export const Buttons = ({ onSelect }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {btnArr.map((btn, index) => (
        <Button key={index} text={btn} onClick={() => onSelect(index)} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now, whenever a button is clicked, the `selectedText` state variable in the `Parent` will be updated to the index of the button clicked.

#### Texts Component

The `Texts` Component is a little bit trickier because we need to show the selected `Text` before the other `Text`s.

Since we are passing in `selectedText` as a prop, we can use that as we are creating the list. Our `Texts` component should look like this:

```
export const Texts = ({ selectedText }) => {
```

The most basic way to order the list is by placing our `selectedText` item first, followed by the mapped over text elements, but with the `selectedText` item filtered out. It may make more sense to look at the code:

```
{<Text text={texts[selectedText]} />}
{texts
  .filter((txt, index) => index !== selectedText)
  .map((txt, index) => (
    <Text key={index} text={txt} />
  ))}
```

That way will work just fine, but if you don't want to have a `<Text ... />` in two places, we can avoid that by using the following code instead. The more complicated way to do this is by using sort: we can sort through the text array to order them and then map over them like this:

```
{texts
  .sort((txt, txt2) =>
    txt === texts[selectedText]
      ? -1
      : txt2 === texts[selectedText]
      ? 1
      : 0
  )
  .map((txt, index) => (
    <Text key={index} text={txt} />
  ))}
```

I've put together a full example of this on CodeSandbox here: [image: Edit amazing-bird-el1vdh]

#### Extending the List

The advantage of doing it this way is that you can easily add more items to the list of buttons/text. If we simply add a `["Toggle Text 4"]` to the button list and a `["Text 4"]` to the text list, you can see that everything still *just works*.

The [CodePen example](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-bird-el1vdh) demonstrates this.

#### Working with Different Files

In my explanation, we worked with three separate files for our code: a parent file, `Texts.js`, and `Buttons.js`.

Here's how you can use the `Texts` and `Buttons` component from inside the parent:

In the parent file at the top, import the other two files like this:

```
import { Texts } from "./Texts";
import { Buttons } from "./Buttons";
```

Then inside `Texts.js`, make sure to have the word `export` before the component is defined like this:

```
export const Texts = ({ selectedText }) => {
```

Do the same in `Buttons.js`:

```
export const Buttons = ({ onSelect }) => {
```

This allows us to use code from one file in a separate file. [This guide](https://charles-bryant.gitbook.io/hello-react-and-typescript/helloworld/componentsinseparatefiles) gives a bit more explanation on how that works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I tried to embed your code in my map project, but for some reason it doesn't filter correctly, and only shows 3 items, although I have 4. Could you follow this link and see my code? I will be grateful for your help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73378537/how-to-change-the-information-when-clicking-on-a-marker-in-react-leaflet

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out that by [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). You can try this but this isn't the best practice you can try make to order with id.

**Buttons.js**

```
const btnArr = [["Togle Text 1"], ["Togle Text 2"], ["Togle Text 3"]];

const Buttons = (props) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "50%" }}>
      {btnArr.map((btn, index) => (
        <button key={index} onClick={() => props.onButtonClick(index)}>
          {btn}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Buttons;
```

**Texts.js**

```
const textArr = [["Text 1"], ["Text 2"], ["Text 3"]];

const Texts = (props) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "50%" }}>
      {<p>{textArr[props.order]}</p>}
      {textArr.map((txt, index) => {
        return index != props.order ? <p key={index}>{txt}</p> : null;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Texts;
```

**App.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Buttons from "./Buttons";
import Texts from "./Text";
function App() {
  const [textIndex, setTextIndex] = useState(0);
  function onButtonClick(buttonIndex) {
    console.log(buttonIndex);
    setTextIndex(buttonIndex);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Buttons onButtonClick={onButtonClick} />
      <Texts order={textIndex} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Notice**: I change the `<Button>` Component and the `<Text>` Component to facilitate the example

Answer (score -1):

My advice would be to look into [React-Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started). This is a state-management system that exists "outside" your component structure in a store. This allows non-related components to speak to each other.

Another option, though less clean would be to send the information from one component to the first parent that contains both components through callbacks, then pass the information through props to the other child component.

EDIT: Redux may be too complex, and too much effort depending on the complexity of the project. Passing through callbacks and props should be enough.